# Why does `cat` on OS X not recognize if the input file matches the output file when appending?

Tags: linux, macos, cat

I am writing a shell for a project and ran the command `cat out >> out` on OS X and was surprised when it just hung. In Linux when you run `cat file >> file` it will identify that the input file matches the output file and raise an error.

On OS X the behavior is that the file will be appended to itself infinitely many times until you run out of space. Is there a reason that `cat` on OS X does not have the same error checking that Linux does?

Comment: Maybe because infinitely concatenating a file to itself is a valid use case in some scenarios?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe if that's the case then why does Linux not support this behavior?

Comment: Not quite sure what a possible answer could be here. Obviously the versions are differing; not surprisingly, since they're different operating systems. You understand what the difference is. It's an easy mistake to avoid. Arguably OS X doesn't question your decisions and accepts you as being the responsible administrator…

Comment: ... so I'm voting to close because this is obviously a very opinion based topic without a proper possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X traditionally uses the BSD version of cat, whereas on Linux the user-land suite of programs tend to be the GNU versions.

In the GNU version of cat, the input/output files are [checked and an error is shown if they are the same](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c#L696)

```
  if (out_isreg
      && stat_buf.st_dev == out_dev && stat_buf.st_ino == out_ino
      && lseek (input_desc, 0, SEEK_CUR) < stat_buf.st_size)
    {
      error (0, 0, _("%s: input file is output file"), quotef (infile));
      ok = false;
      goto contin;
    }
```

The version of cat [included in OS X does not include a redirection check](https://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-81/cat/cat.c), it seems to be based on the Net BSD version.

Comment: I understand that they are different distributions, I suppose what I'm wondering is are there any real use cases of `cat file >> file` or is the BSD distribution simply lagging behind?

Comment: @Nick There are any number of edge cases in any system which you can find if you dig long enough. Linux/GNU happened to fix this particular edge case because someone somewhere thought it was a good idea to do so. BSD did not happen to do the same for whatever reason. Thinking about these kinds of things in terms of "lagging behind" is not useful. They're *different* due to different evolutional paths, period.

Comment: Let's be honest though... the GNU version **is** better. There's no good use case for `cat x >> x`. From my utterly biased point of view OS X does look like it is lagging behind!